# Get Week Number From Date off one week

Tags: php, date

Trying to get the week number from a given date within PHP.  For some reason various things I try seem to be a week off.

Looking at the following link we should be on week 3
http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php

Yet when I do the following I get week 2

```
echo "Weeknummer: " . date("W", strtotime("2016-01-17"));
```

I've also tried this code getting the same result, week 2

```
$date = new DateTime("2016-01-17");
$week = $date->format("W");
echo "Weeknummer: $week";
```

Any ideas why its seems to be a week behind and how I can fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Man, you provided link to http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php and there is date "2016-01-17" and it is week 2. So - all is OK, right? And if you try with "2016-01-18" - it will be week 3.

Comment: The week starting on Monday vs Sunday threw me off, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you sent shows that 2016-01-17 is on week 2. See screenshot. In PHP the weeks start on Monday (you can read more [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We are, but today is the 19th (at least in my time-zone...).

You have hard-coded the 17th in your script and as you can see in the site that you mentioned, that is the last day of week 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in mktime(), it goes like this:

```
mktime(hour, minute, second, month, day, year);
```

so try with the below code hope it's what you want

```
<?php
$ddate = "2016-01-17";
$duedt = explode("-", $ddate);
$date  = mktime(0, 0, 0, $duedt[1], $duedt[2], $duedt[0]);
$week  = (int)date('W', $date);
echo "Weeknummer: " . $week;
?>
```

also you can try github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon to maximize your skills in Date manipulation. For carbon you can do that by:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '2012-10-18')->format('W');
```